# Apply function returning a 1D array to all elements of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array of `d` dimensions, and I want to apply a function which returns a 1D array to each element, yielding a `d+1`-dimensional array. Very much as an embedding lookup works. For instance:

```
def f(x):
    return np.array([x * i for i in range(6)])

m = np.random.randint(0,10, (2,3,4,5))

g = np.vectorize(f)
h = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.ndarray])
```

I expect `n=g(m)` to have shape `(2,3,4,5,6)` just as if I had written 4 `for` loops, applying `f` to each element in `m`.

However, `g` raises an error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` and `h` returns an odd array ending like:

```
...
[array([0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72]),
array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]),
array([0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56]), ...,
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
array([0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32]),
array([0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24])]]]], dtype=object)
```

which I can't change to what I expect.

I get @hpaulj's comment, I just can't find how to do otherwise.

Comment: That's normal.  Your `f` returns an array for a scalar `x`.  Creates a result array of shape matching `x`.  It can only put the array in an `object` dtype array.

Comment: I should rephrase: I get why there is an issue, can you think of an alternatives which does not imply `for` loops?

Comment: `vectorize` iterates on elements of `x`; it just hides that.  It's slower than an explicit loop.

Comment: Ok, good to know; is there any alternative to `vectorize` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vectorize` has added a `signature` parameter that does what you want.  However it is even slower than the `otypes` approach.  Still for completeness, I'll illustrate:

```
In [198]: def f(x):
     ...:     return np.array([x * i for i in range(6)])
In [199]: g = np.vectorize(f, signature='()->(6)')
```

It takes any shape array, and returns a new one with an added size 6 dimension:

```
In [202]: g(1)
Out[202]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [203]: g(np.array([1,2]))
Out[203]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
In [204]: g(np.array([[1],[2]]))
Out[204]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10]]])
```

---

To do this faster, you have write `f` in a way that makes use of the compiled `numpy` methods.  There isn't a function that will take a Python function and rewrite it to be faster.

For this `f` we can take advantage of numpy broadcasting and write:

```
In [205]: def fn(x):
     ...:     return x[...,None] * np.arange(6)
     ...: 

In [207]: fn(np.array(1))
Out[207]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [208]: fn(np.array([1,2]))
Out[208]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
In [209]: fn(np.array([[1],[2]]))
Out[209]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10]]])
```

Here the vectorization was easy.  Sometimes it requires some clever thinking, and sometimes it's impossible (especially if the problem is inherently serial in nature).  There are tools for producing faster compiled code from iterative solutions, such as `numba` and `cython`.